# get All File from folder in php

Tags: php, json, directory

> folder structure

```
Main Folder
     ->(1)SS (subFolder) contain 15 Png Images
     -> Main Movie File (700Mb)
     -> Sample.mkv (14Mb)
```

> php code

```
$dir = "download/a176b8a9f5575a08eac602adfdc78f666e3695a2";

$response = scan($dir);

function scan($dir){
           if(file_exists($dir)){
            foreach(scandir($dir) as $f) {
              if(!$f || $f[0] == '.') {
                continue; // Ignore hidden files
              }

            if(is_dir($dir . '/' . $f)) {

                // The path is a folder

                $files = scan($dir . '/' . $f); // Recursively get the contents of the folder}

            else {

                // It is a file

                $files[] = array(
                    "name" => $f,
                    "type" => "file",
                    "path" => $dir . '/' . $f,
                    "size" => filesize($dir . '/' . $f) // Gets the size of this file

                );
            }
        }

    }
return $files;

}
```

header('Content-type: application/json');

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

> The problem Is i get All File Expect Main Movie File (700Mb) 
>     here is
>        [Working Example](https://oceanmovies.in/21/)
>
> Also Need Sorting show 700mb First then show other file

Comment: Is the main video file even missing in the returned array of `scandir($dir)`?

Comment: yes main video is mission in return of scandir($dir) but its exits on sever  if i delete any png file then main video file show in json_encode

Comment: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/6akIyag4u.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

class MyRecursiveFilterIterator extends RecursiveFilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        if (substr($this->current()->getFilename(), 0, 1) !== '.') {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }

}
$dir = 'dirname';
$dirItr = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
$dirItr->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$filterItr = new MyRecursiveFilterIterator($dirItr);
$itr = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filterItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$itr->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
foreach ($itr as $filePath => $fileInfo) {
  if ($fileInfo->isFile()) {
    $final[$fileInfo->getSize()][] = $fileInfo->getPathName(); //alternatively you can use $fileInfo->getFilename();
  }
}

krsort($final);
echo '<pre>';print_r(($final));
```

this should work for you. customize the output accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why not using [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)?
2. You can try using [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead if scandir

   foreach( glob( $log_directory . '/*.*' ) as $file ) {
       // Function goes here..
   }